# NSDictionary throws exception not logical for me

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

Good day.Im requesting to some server and defiantly I'm having some JSON data there so I'm trying to parse it.Im stuck at the point where I'm actually parsing it.So i have method called parseJson which requires NSDictionry as parameter so here how it looks

```
-(void)parseJson:(NSDictionary*)jsonData{


    [jsonData valueForKey:@"email"];



}
```

as you can see not much here but I'm getting exeption when the code reaches at

`[jsonData valueForKey:@"email"];`

I have pretty much started developing for iOS from yesterday and the exception is hell as weird for me which is the next.

this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.'

So by googling i found nothing...and pretty much in every JSON PARSING tutorial  this one line code is written so I'm very much confused what does this exception means....Please help,what am i doing wrong?

FULL REQUEST CODE

```
-(void) makeRequest{
    // Create the request.
    __block NSString *returnResponse = @"hello";
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue ]];

    //Create an URLRequest
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Create POST Params and add it to HTTPBody
    NSString *params = @"api_key=APIKEY&email=example@example.com&password=password";
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Create task
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest: urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


        if(response!=NULL){
            returnResponse =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response];
        }else{
            returnResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.description];
        }
        [self hideSpinner];
        NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [self parseJson:jsonString];
    }];


    [dataTask resume];


}
```

Ok i have changed the method now to

```
-(void)parseJson:(NSString*)jsonData{

    NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonData];


     NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);

    NSString* mystring = [dictionary valueForKey:@"email"];

    NSLog(@"%@",mystring);



}
```

and here is the output i get when logging the strings

```
2016-01-22 00:25:48.690 testproject[627:83537] {
  "api_key": "APIKEY",
  "email": "example@example.com",
  "password": "password",
  "id": 101
}
2016-01-22 00:25:48.690 testproject[627:83537] (null)
```

As you can see the exception problem gone,but now i get NULL value..but you can see that just a one line above i got my son with email key string....so i have fully no clue whats going on.

Comment: have you tried simply `jsonData[@"email"]`?

Comment: ...............im new to iOS :D only 2 days ....i`m on android expert not on iOS :D so anyways ill try it see whats going on there...

Comment: ok when i try that i got another exception...... :/ damn this iOS exception descriptions so weird can't understand anything at all....

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Okay, please give a little bit more context in your question, the calling ode for example

Comment: this feeling when you start developing before getting know basic stuff

Comment: ok ill edit it with full request code

Comment: ok i edited:) oh yeah true :)

Comment: Ehm - just a tiny hint: look at the warnings in your code. They should mention something about sending NSString* to NSDictionary*

Comment: hey wait........lemme log!

Comment: dang it now i did not get exception but i get null...nothing....but i know for 100 percent that the email is there.....anyway here what i changed in mode

Comment: NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonData];
    
    NSString* mystring = dictionary[@"email"];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",mystring);

Comment: You have an NSString (`jsonString`) that you are passing as NSDictionary, then try to call a method from NSDictionary to that NSString, yeah, that won't work because strings can't be casted into dictionaries like that, even if it's a JSON string. You need a JSON parser.

Comment: hmm so for what in hell then i need initWithContentsOFfILE  METHOD in NSDictionary?

Comment: ok and i have changed the method check the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueForObject:`method has nothing to do with `NSDictionary`. It is used by [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) which stands for Key-Value Observing. You can retrieve object from `NSDictionary` by using `[]` or `objectForKey:` method. Here are the examples:

```
dictionary[@"email"] 
//or
[dictionary objectForKey:@"email"]
```

//**EDITED**

Instead of converting `NSObject` to `NSString` and trying accessing properties with `KVO` or dictionary methods/syntax please try to parse NSData using the code below:

```
     NSDictionary *JSONDictionary =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]
     NSString *email = JSONDictionary[@"email"];
```

You should be able to retrieve objects from the `JSONDictionary` using methods/syntax mentioned by me in the first version of the answer.

Comment: If you don't find my answer valuable please let me know and I will remove it. I believed that explaining the reason of your problem and referencing KVO documentation will help you learning.

Comment: trying to understand the problem is that i know that...i tried that but did not working for me....